# Variable value is ridiculous in function call when debugging my c++ code with gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

There's something rediculous happened when i debug my c++ code with GDB.
a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void square(int a, int y)
{
    int temp = 7;
    a = y;
    y = temp;
    temp = 6;
}
void square2(int a, int y)
{
    int temp = 7;
    a = temp;
    y = temp;
    temp = 6;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0, y = 5;
    square(a, y);
    square2(a, y);
    return 0;
}
```

The compile cmd is `g++ -g -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test`

When I launch GDB and step into square, the local variable temp is 7 for sure when i reach the `a = y` expression. But when I reach the `temp = 6`, i try to print the variable value of a and y, which was 0 and 7. That is strange as a should be 5 and y should be 7, as i concerned.
AND in the call of square2, reaching the same place of `temp = 6`, the value of a and y printed by gdb is 0 and 5, totally remain unchanged!

Could someone figure out what is going on during the execution of the code? That quite drives me mad!

Comment: You need to pass by reference.  `void square(int a, int y) => void square(int &a, int &y)`

Comment: Can't be reproduced at ideone.com. The print inside `square` gives `a 5` and `y 7`. And for `square2`  `a 7` and `y 7`. See http://ideone.com/e.js/OXV3DL

Comment: @Daniel - you should add the code used for printing - maybe that is your problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver - that is not the solution to the problem described.

Comment: Although you are not violating the rules of C and C++, overriding the function arguments locally is unorthodox.  The debugger has the arguments as the scope name for 'a' rather than the temporary value in the register.  Disassemble the code and examine the register and stack.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis - no it is not `unorthodox`. In fact it is very common (and safe) when passed by value.

Comment: Looks like an optimization. Same behavior if compiled as C. Assigning to an arg like `a` prior to any reference to the arg writes to an area on the stack where local variables are stored - not to the register the arg was passed in, and not to the register parameter area. The DWARF information doesn't include that info, though, at least with gcc 4.8.4, and that's a bug.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - works fine for `gcc version 5.3.0 (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`

Comment: gcc 4.9.2 with default optimization generates code that's more like one would expect. The assignment to `a` writes to the value in the register parameter area (on x86_64). @Daniel, what version of gcc are you running?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - have you added code that prints the variables inside `square` and `square2`?

Comment: @StillLearning No, I am using OP's code without adding anything. I'm using `gdb` print commands. Well, I've experimented with various things, including using `a` before its assignment and using it after its assignment in another function call, just to see how the code changes.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - in that case the compiler may do whatever it wants to as there are no side effects of the function call. With -O3 it should remove the whole thing. Try to add `cout << a << " " << y << endl;` just before the last assignment to temp. Doesn't that solve the problem?

Comment: @StillLearning I understand it's an optimization. But adding `cout << a << " " << y << endl;` on gcc 4.8.4 shows a genuine bug as far as telling a debugger how to retrieve `a`'s value. The prologue in `square` does `mov %edi,-0x14(%rbp)` `%esi,-0x18(%rbp)` to spill `a` and `y` to the register parameter area. `a=y` does `mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax` `mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)`. An attempt in gdb to `print a` at this point still retrieves the value at `-0x14(%rbp)`. `cout << a << " " << y << endl;` does `mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax`. The generated code is correct, but the debugging info is deficient.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - thanks for the update. So the program is correct but gdb is displaying things incorrectly. Interresting. I never used gdb that much but from time to time I have to, so it is good to know. Thanks. If you are sure about your findings, maybe you should write an answer :)

Comment: @StillLearning I tried adding the printing codes after the `y = temp` expression but it does not change the value printed by gdb after printing code, just the same as that without printing code. But the value printed on stdout is correnct, quite strange. My gcc version is 4.8.4.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the experiment. My gcc version is 4.8.4. I know little about the debugging info and how the debugger get the value but as you said, the incorrect debugging info generated by gcc caused this bug, and the code generated is quite the one we expected. Is that right ? I'll update my gcc to see the results.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yeah after upgrading my gcc to 5.3.0 the value printed by gdb is just the ones I expected. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

If your code has no visible side effects, the compiler is free to do any kind of optimization on the code, e.g. not changing the value of the variables. A good compiler with optimization turned on should actually remove all your code.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void square(int a, int y)
{
    int temp = 7;
    a = y;
    y = temp;
    cout << "a=" << a << " y=" << y << endl;
    temp = 6;
}
void square2(int a, int y)
{
    int temp = 7;
    a = temp;
    y = temp;
    cout << "a=" << a << " y=" << y << endl;
    temp = 6;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0, y = 5;
    square(a, y);
    square2(a, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Then you'll get the correct values printed.

Comment: It doest change the value printed by gdb, unfortunately, although the value on stdout is the correct ones. It seems to be the gcc 4.8 issue and after upgrading gcc to 5.3.0 the values printed by gdb is just the ones I expected.